# Python how to convert this for loop into a while loop

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting a for loop to a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610623/converting-a-for-loop-to-a-while-loop)

I have this for a for loop which I made I was wondering how I would write so it would work with a while loop.

```
def scrollList(myList):
    negativeIndices=[]
    for i in range(0,len(myList)):
        if myList[i]<0:
            negativeIndices.append(i)
    return negativeIndices
```

So far I have this

```
def scrollList2(myList):
    negativeIndices=[]
    i= 0
    length= len(myList)
    while i != length:
        if myList[i]<0:
            negativeIndices.append(i)
            i=i+1

    return negativeIndices
```

Comment: @user1690198 I'd look at how for loops work first - loop directly over the list, not over a range of indicies. (``[index for index, value in enumerate(myList) if value < 0]``)

Comment: `scrollList = lambda lst: [i for i,v in enumerate(lst) if v<0]`

Comment: This was just asked by another user. You guys should not use SO to do your homework.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It's homework.

Comment: The teacher that assigned it needs to be fired for wasting their students' time.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Or at least for teaching them to write `for i in range(x): … x[i] …` loops…

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question

Answer (score 6):

Well, you are nearly there. It's like this:

```
def scrollList2(myList):
    negativeIndices=[]
    i= 0
    length= len(myList)
    while i != length:
        if myList[i]<0:
            negativeIndices.append(i)
        i=i+1

    return negativeIndices
```

The problem you had is that you must increment the loop index on each iteration. You were only incrementing when you found a negative value.

---

But it's better as a `for` loop and your `for` loop is over complicated. I'd write it like this:

```
def scrollList(myList):
    negativeIndices=[]
    for index, item in enumerate(myList):
        if item<0:
            negativeIndices.append(index)
    return negativeIndices
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, for one, your incrementer `i` should always be updated, instead of just when you meet the condition. Only doing it in the `if` statement means you're only ever advancing when you see a returnable element, so if your first element doesn't meet your condition, your function will hang. Oops. This would work better:

```
def scrollList2(myList):
    negativeIndices=[]
    i= 0
    length= len(myList)
    while i != length:
        if myList[i]<0:
            negativeIndices.append(i)
        i=i+1

    return negativeIndices
```